# Find object by match property in nested array

Tags: lodash

I'm not seeing a way to `find` objects when my condition would involve a nested array.

```
var modules = [{
    name: 'Module1',
    submodules: [{
        name: 'Submodule1',
        id: 1
      }, {
        name: 'Submodule2',
        id: 2
      }
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Module2',
    submodules: [{
        name: 'Submodule1',
        id: 3
      }, {
        name: 'Submodule2',
        id: 4
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

This won't work because `submodules` is an array, not an object. Is there any shorthand that would make this work? I'm trying to avoid iterating the array manually.

```
_.where(modules, {submodules:{id:3}});
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```js
_.find(modules, _.flow(
    _.property('submodules'),
    _.partialRight(_.some, { id: 2 })
));
// → { name: 'Module1', ... }
```

Using [flow()](https://lodash.com/docs#flow), you can construct a callback function that does what you need. When call, the data *flows* through each function. The first thing you want is the `submodules` property, and you can get that using the [property()](https://lodash.com/docs#property) function.

The the submodules array is then fed into [some()](https://lodash.com/docs#some), which returns true if it contains the submodule you're after, in this case, ID `2`.

Replace `find()` with `filter()` if you're looking for multiple modules, and not just the first one found.

Comment: I like it, thanks! Not quite as elegant as a dynamic path could be, but lodash doesn't support that. Maybe I'll make a mixin...

Comment: FYI, in Lodash 4.0, they removed the .any() function.  Now you would use .some().

Answer (score 90):

Lodash allows you to filter in nested data (including arrays) like this:

`_.filter(modules, { submodules: [ { id: 2 } ]});`

Comment: You can use the exact same syntax with `_.find` as well.

Comment: @DevonSams although `_.filter` returns the filtered array or an empty array and `_.find` returns the matched element which could be an object, array, number, string, boolean or undefined.

Comment: Is there any way to just return that nested object instead of whole parent object?

Comment: how can I target an object inside an array of barcodes which is inside a sizes array and that sizes array is inside a colors array...How can I directly point to barcodes?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best chance is using a function, for obtaining the module.

```
_.select(modules, function (module) {
  return _.any(module.submodules, function (submodule) {
    return _.where(submodule, {id:3});
  });
});
```

try this for getting the submodule

*.where(*.pluck(modules, "submodules"), {submodules:{id:3}});

Comment: Good idea. I have to use `_flatten` in addition because `_.pluck` returns an array of arrays.

Comment: (yes flatten came to my mind later), but i changed my answer completely, because it wouldn't work. hopeful thinking :)

Comment: But it did work. Using the flatten+pluck logic, my test works. http://jsbin.com/howazulexe/1/edit?js

Comment: i thought the aim is to obtain the parent module, not the submodule. in that case then, yes :D

Comment: Oh, good thought. Not in my case, but that's an equally useful use-case. If you want to update your answer with both, I'll mark it accepted. I'm not seeing anything cleaner. Honestly, I'm surprised there's no matcher support.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this and I think the best option is to use [Deepdash](https://deepdash.io).  It's a collection of methods to do deeply filter, find etc.

Sure it would be possible with lodash alone but with Deepdash it's easier.

I tried to convert the previous answer to the latest Lodash version but that was not working. Every method was deprecated in v4 of Lodash. Possible replacements: select = map or filter, any = some, where = filter)

`findDeep` returns an object with some information to the found item (just some values, see the [docs](https://deepdash.io/#finddeep) for more details):

- `value` is the object found
- `key` that's the index in the nested array
- `parent` the parent of the value

So the code for the `findDeep` looks like:

```js
const modules = [{
  name: 'Module1',
  submodules: [{
    name: 'Submodule1',
    id: 1
  }, {
    name: 'Submodule2',
    id: 2
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Module2',
  submodules: [{
    name: 'Submodule1',
    id: 3
  }, {
    name: 'Submodule2',
    id: 4
  }]
}];

const getModule = (modules, id) =>
  _.findDeep(modules, module => module.id === id, {
    childrenPath: "submodules"
  });


const resultEl = document.getElementById("result");
const foundModule = getModule(modules, 3).value;

resultEl.innerText = JSON.stringify(foundModule, null, 2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/deepdash/browser/deepdash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script>
  deepdash(_);
</script>

<h2>Example to get module with id = 3</h2>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be:

```
const var = _.find(modules, (item) => {
        return (item.submodules.id === 2)
      })
```

You can either user `_.find` to get the first occurrence or `_.filter` to get all ot them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search all by keyword:

```
const searchWord = 'Hello world'.trim().toLowerCase();
const result = JSON.stringify(object).trim().toLowerCase().includes(searchWord);
```

1. Trim and lowercase search word(s).
2. Stringify object, trim and lowercase.
3. Check if it includes the search word(s).