# lodash filter by name

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I'm trying to figure out how to use lodash to filter the following object:

```
contacts = {
  A: [
  { name: "Albert", age: 16 },
  { name: "Arthur", age: 24}
  ],
  B: [
  { name: "Bob", age: 33 }
  ],
  C: [],
  D: [],
...
};
```

I'd like to be able to filter contacts by name (contains) while keeping the same structure, I don't know to tell lodash to look for any objects on the 2nd level.

Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: how should the output look like?

Comment: Maybe you could use `Object.entries` then `Object.prototype.filter`, What are you going for?

Comment: @gurvinder372 The output should look the same without the entries that doesn't match the search filter. If the search is "A" then the bob entry gets removed, if the search is "th", then bob and Albert gets removed, etc...

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30107463/find-object-by-match-property-in-nested-array

Comment: Thanks @JunBach the problem is on this question, everything is contained in 'submodules', in my case the contacts are contained in "A", "B", "C", "D", etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```js
const contacts = {
  A: [
  { name: "Albert", age: 16 },
  { name: "Arthur", age: 24}
  ],
  B: [
  { name: "Bob", age: 33 },
  { name: "Ahn", age: 20 },
  ],
  C: [],
  D: []
};

const obj = {};
Object.keys(contacts).forEach(index => {
  obj[index] = contacts[index].filter(person =>
    person.name.includes("th"));
});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and `filter`

```
var nameToSearch = "Bob";
contacts = Object.keys(contacts).map( s => contacts[s].filter( t => t.name == nameToSearch ) );
```