# Filter object by tag (array inside an array of objects)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

### **The Objective**

***Edit - making the question more clear***

To create a search that can narrow search results based on the item's tags and only return the items that have the specified tags. 
Example: ['green'] will give me all items that are green including big, medium and small (since no size was specified), ['green','big'] will give me only the items that are green and big.

I ran into a scenario. To simplify things, i have the following data

```
items: [
    { title: 'prod1', tags: [{ value: 'green' }, { value: 'big' }] },
    { title: 'prod2', tags: [{ value: 'blue' }, { value: 'small' }] },
    { title: 'prod3', tags: [{ value: 'yellow' }, { value: 'medium' }, { value: 'big' }] },
    { title: 'prod4', tags: [{ value: 'green' }, { value: 'big' }, { value: 'medium' }] },
]
```

my search field is a multiple selection input takes predefined tags (like the tags field in this website)
the value of this field is outputted as an array. if i select `green` the output is ['green']
if i select `green` and `big` it outputs ['green', 'big']

if i select tag `green` i should get back these results

```
{ title: 'prod1', tags: [{ value: 'green' }, { value: 'big' }] },
{ title: 'prod4', tags: [{ value: 'green' }, { value: 'big' }, { value: 'medium' }] },
```

if i select tags `green` and `medium` i get these results, because prod4 is the only one that has tags green and medium

```
{ title: 'prod4', tags: [{ value: 'green' }, { value: 'big' }, { value: 'medium' }] },
```

if i select `green` and `big` i should get

```
{ title: 'prod4', tags: [{ value: 'green' }, { value: 'big' }, { value: 'medium' }] },
{ title: 'prod1', tags: [{ value: 'green' }, { value: 'big' }] }
```

**if nothing is selected, then output all the items**

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

```
I ran into a scenario. To simplify things, i have the following data

items: [
  {title: 'one', desc: 'this is one', tags: [{value: 'mytag'},{value: 'one'}]},
  {title: 'two', desc: 'this is two', tags: [{value: 'mytag'},{value: two}]},
  {title: 'three', desc: 'this is three', tags: [{value: 'mytag'},{value: 'three'},{value: 'common'}]},
  {title: 'four', desc: 'this is four', tags: [{value: 'mytag'},{value: 'four'},{value: 'common'}]},
]
```

i have a search input element that accepts tags and the value of the input is an array. The input will have its value as `['tag','two']`
I can't seem to figure out how to filter my items by tags.

if i search by tag two ( `['two']`) i should get a returned

```
filteredItems: [
   {title: 'two', desc: 'this is two', tags: [{value: 'mytag'},{value: two}]},
]
```

if i search with two, common (`['two','common']`) i should get a returned

```
filteredItems: [
  {title: 'three', desc: 'this is three', tags: [{value: 'mytag'},{value: 'three'},{value: 'common'}]},
  {title: 'four', desc: 'this is four', tags: [{value: 'mytag'},{value: 'four'},{value: 'common'}]},
]
```

i tried looking at some examples, and i found some that only filter top level items and not nested arrays.

thanks :)
using javascript by the way, lodash may be used.

My playground JS file:

```
const _ = require('lodash')

let items = [
    {
        name: 'hello',
        tags: [
            { value: 1 },
            { value: 2 },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'bye',
        tags: [
            { value: 2 },
            { value: 4 },
        ]
    }
]
items.map(item =>{

    let test = _.includes(item.tags, 2)
    console.log(test)
// returns false, false
})
```

Comment: Why does searching for `['two','common']` not include the `two` object?

Comment: this is the way the search dropdown (using semantic ui) list spits out its value.. with an array of strings..

Comment: In the first code block you did not use the string literal `'two'`, but the variable with that name.

Comment: So? Regardless of format, why isn't the `two` object matched when `two` is searched for? I'm not getting it

Comment: what is the value of `two`? Where do you define it?

Comment: sorry it was a typo, its a string. i fixed it in the question

Comment: I don't get why `['two','common']` is only supposed to return two matches (the ones with "common") and not three (also including the one with "two"). Why is that?

Comment: Because the search needs to return only the objects that have 'two' and 'common' as tags. This is so that i can narrow down a search based on the tags the item has. For example. First search.. give me all items with the tag green. then if i want to narrow the search even further, i can say, search for items that have the green tag, but also must have the big tag. there could be items that have a green tag but could also possibly have "small" "big" "medium"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(NB: the first part of this answer relates to the original question before it was edited)

You need to go one level deeper. Your final *playground* code is comparing an object with 2, but you should compare an object *property* with 2.

```
let test = items.filter(item =>{
    return item.tags.some(obj => obj.value === 2)
})
```

Or, if the value to look for is in the other property:

```
let test = items.filter(item =>{
    return item.tags.some(obj => obj.text === 'two')
})
```

### After the edit to your question

Your example data can be searched like this:

```js
function search(items, constraints) {
    return items.filter(item =>
        constraints.every(constraint => 
            item.tags.some(obj => obj.value === constraint)
        )
    );
}

const items = [
    { title: 'prod1', tags: [{ value: 'green' }, { value: 'big' }] },
    { title: 'prod2', tags: [{ value: 'blue' }, { value: 'small' }] },
    { title: 'prod3', tags: [{ value: 'yellow' }, { value: 'medium' }, { value: 'big' }] },
    { title: 'prod4', tags: [{ value: 'green' }, { value: 'big' }, { value: 'medium' }] },
];

console.log(search(items, ["green", "medium"]));
```

The logic you need is a combination of AND and OR logic: for an array element to match the given constraints, it should have *some* matching object (OR) for *every* value (AND) in the given constraints.

Comment: yup this works.. at least for my playground test.. however, i'm still trying to figure out the solution to my original problem which is searching/filtering with an array.

Comment: Added how this can be applied to your original problem.

Comment: getting closer.. instead of "two" OR "common", it would have to be "two" AND "common". i updated my question with a bit more info, may be that can be more clear. i tried using indexOf inside the .some function to return anything thats !== -1, and that works only when searching a single tag. but as soon as i add my second tag (`['tag1','tag2']`) i get nothing returned. BY THE WAY, thank you so much, i feel like i'm getting a lot closer.

Comment: That depends: if you need all conditions (provided in the input array) to be true for one match, then you need `every` (but then your example in your question is even more wrong: there are no records that have *both* "two" and "common"). If on the other hand it is enough that a match has at least one value that was provided in the input, then you need `some`. But then your example for `["two", "common"]` should give 3 results instead of 2. If you can make your question more clear & consistent as to what you need in that example, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: there, i updated the question. my apologies. i wasn't very clear.

Comment: Thanks. It is a pity though that you deleted your failing attempt from your question, as now it becomes a non-question, but an exercise, which is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I updated my answer to your new version anyway: you need a combination of `every` and `some`.

Comment: i see, i have included the original question for others to be able to follow.. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30107463/find-object-by-match-property-in-nested-array) from martinoss

Solution:

using lodash filter function

```
let filteredItems = _.filter(items, {tags: [{value: 'green'},{value: 'big'}]}
console.log(filteredItems)

// { title: 'prod1', tags: [{ value: 'green' }, { value: 'big' }] },
// { title: 'prod4', tags: [{ value: 'green' }, { value: 'big' }, { value: 'medium' }] },
```

this will return only the object that has the two tags (green and big).

i did have to modify the array and convert it to object (my selection outputs the value as ['green','big']

i did that by doing the following:

```
let search = ['green', 'big']

search = search.map(searchTag => {
    return {value: searchTag}
})

// [{value: 'green'},{value: 'big'}]
```

if theres a vanilla es6 way of doing it, i'd love to see it.. for now this works for me

Answer (score 0):

The below code shouold accomplish what you want, if the constraints variable in search is null, undefined, '', [] or not supplied then the items are returned with no filtering.  If the constraints variable is a string the assumption is one constraint which is applied to the items that are returned, if the constraints is an Array then all constraints are applied.  I tried to name the variables in a self explanatory manner.

```
var search = (items, constraints) => {
    //no constraints supplied, null, undefined, '', or empty array
  if ( !constraints || constraints === '' || (Array.isArray(constraints) && constraints.length === 0) ) {
    return items;
  }

  let match = false;
  let cons = [];

  //constraints is a string with one constraint add it to an array
  if (typeof constraints === 'string') {
    cons.push(constraints);
  }

  //if constraints is an array of constraints 1 or more
  if (Array.isArray(constraints)) {
    cons.concat(constraints);
    return items.filter( (item) => {
      match = true;
      let itemTags = item.tags.map( (tag) => tag.value );
      cons.forEach( (constraint) => {
        if (constraint === '') return;
        match = (itemTags.indexOf(constraint) > -1 && match);
      } );
      return match;
    } );

  }

};
```