# Filtering a JavaScript object with nested structure

Tags: javascript

```
let data = [
    {
        title: 'aa',
        releases: [
            { version: '1', owner: 'john'},
            { version: '2', owner: 'bob'}
        ]
    },
    {
        title: 'bb',
        releases: [
            { version: '1', owner: 'john'},
            { version: '2', owner: 'jack'}
        ]
    },
    {
        title: 'cc',
        releases: [
            { version: '1', owner: 'doo'},
            { version: '2', owner: 'park'}
        ]
    },
]
```

I have an array of objects that looks like above.

I am trying to filter the objects by the `owner` inside the `releases` array.

What I've tried is

```
data.filter(item => 
        ['john'].some(
            item.releases.some(
                obj=>obj.owner.toLowerCase().includes(['john'])
            )
        )
    )
```

I used an array of string(s) to have multiple search queries in the future. But this gives me an error

`Uncaught TypeError: true is not a function`

How can I solve this?

The result should be all objects that have `john` as an owner in any of its `releases` array

Comment: `some` takes a function; you're passing the result of a separate `some` call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter nested array in object array by array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650390/filter-nested-array-in-object-array-by-array-of-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `['john'].some(` call isn't really helping. You have the logic already without that.

You are getting that error because you are passing the result of `some()` (which returns a boolean) to `some()` (which expect a function).

Also, when asking if a string includes a string, you should pass in a string, not an array.

```
const filteredData = data.filter(item => 
    item.releases.some(
        obj => obj.owner.toLowerCase().includes('john')
    )
)
```

Comment: It should be noted that `data.filter()` returns a *new* array, and won't change the original `data` array.

Comment: I'm also fairly certain that `String.includes()` first argument only accepts strings.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon You would think, but it does actually work as is. Though, probably via string coercion. Answer updated.

Comment: @AlexWayne Indeed, you are right. Don't you like untyped languages? :)

Answer (score 0):

some expects a function not value, in the outer most some you're just passing the value you need to pass function instead

```
data.filter(item =>  
        ['john'].some( () =>      //  <--- function
            item.releases.some(
                obj=>obj.owner.toLowerCase().includes('john')
            )
        )
    )
```

Infact you don't need outer some

```
data.filter(item =>  
     item.releases.some(
       obj=>obj.owner.toLowerCase().includes('john')
    )
)
```

Comment: @Pointy i just copied OP's code to show what is the real problem in code, add a version without some too

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
let data = [
    {
        title: 'aa',
        releases: [
            { version: '1', owner: 'john'},
            { version: '2', owner: 'bob'}
        ]
    },
    {
        title: 'bb',
        releases: [
            { version: '1', owner: 'john'},
            { version: '2', owner: 'jack'}
        ]
    },
    {
        title: 'cc',
        releases: [
            { version: '1', owner: 'doo'},
            { version: '2', owner: 'park'}
        ]
    },
];

var result = data.filter(x => x.releases.some(rls => rls.owner.toLowerCase().includes(['john'])));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to check for a single name you can negate this answer. However if the intent of the question is to check for multiple names you can fix your code in the following way.

The issue is that you're providing a `true`/`false` value to the first `some` call, this should be a function.

```
const names = ['john'];
data.filter(item =>
  names.some(name => // added `name =>`
    item.releases.some(release =>
      release.owner.toLowerCase().includes(name) // changed `['john']` into `name`
    )
  )
);
```

However, you can also achieve the same functionality with less iterations by using an regex.

```
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Escaping
const escapeRegExp = string => string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');

const names = ['john'],
      pattern = names.map(escapeRegExp).join("|"),
      regex = new RegExp(pattern, "i"); // i = ignore case (removing the need of toLowerCase)

data.filter(item => item.releases.some(release => release.owner.match(regex)));
```