# Filter a object by single value js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, filter

I have a JSON data below:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 3844,
            "sku": "aaa",
            "name": "aaa",
            "attribute_set_id": 4,
            "price": 2222,
            "status": 1,
            "visibility": 4,
            "type_id": "simple",
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "special_price",
                    "value": "2222.000000"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "brand",
                    "value": "5465"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "category_ids",
                    "value": [
                        "75",
                        "791",
                        "793",
                        "799"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "color",
                    "value": "5447"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "size",
                    "value": "5432"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3843,
            "sku": "HV 119",
            "name": "Engine valve-Bajaj Pulsar 180cc DTSi",
            "attribute_set_id": 4,
            "price": 292,
            "status": 1,
            "visibility": 4,
            "type_id": "simple",
            "created_at": "2020-04-06 07:48:29",
            "updated_at": "2020-04-06 07:48:29",
            "weight": 0.25,
            "tier_prices": [],
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "special_price",
                    "value": "292.000000"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "brand",
                    "value": "777"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "category_ids",
                    "value": [
                        "75",
                        "793",
                        "1350"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3842,
            "sku": "HV 118",
            "name": "Engine valve-Bajaj Pulsar 150cc DTSi / DIS.125",
            "attribute_set_id": 4,
            "price": 274,
            "status": 1,
            "visibility": 4,
            "type_id": "simple",
            "created_at": "2020-04-06 07:46:01",
            "updated_at": "2020-04-06 07:46:01",
            "weight": 0.25,
            "tier_prices": [],
            "custom_attributes": [               
                {
                    "attribute_code": "special_price",
                    "value": "274.000000"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "category_ids",
                    "value": [
                        "75",
                        "793",
                        "1350"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "search_criteria": {
        "filter_groups": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "field": "category_id",
                        "value": "75",
                        "condition_type": "eq"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "sort_orders": [
            {
                "field": "position",
                "direction": "DESC"
            }
        ],
        "page_size": 3,
        "current_page": 1
    },
    "total_count": 3
}
```

And I have a value **777**. I'm in need of the above data, first element has a array of `custom_attributes>attribute_code === brand` and it's value === 777. I have to filter in such way. Also in second data I don't have the `custom_attributes->attribute_code === brand` even exist. So I'm supposed to remove that data and finally in need of a filtered array. Also in other case there is a data matching the array `category_ids` in `custom_attribute` which is a array. So using a specific value like `793` I also need to filter.

The Code I tried is below

```
 let overAll = filt.items.filter(c => c.custom_attributes.map((i,j)=>{
                if(i.attribute_code === "brand"){
                    return i.value === 777
                }
            }))
```

**Expexted Output:**

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 3844,
            "sku": "aaa",
            "name": "aaa",
            "attribute_set_id": 4,
            "price": 2222,
            "status": 1,
            "visibility": 4,
            "type_id": "simple",
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "special_price",
                    "value": "2222.000000"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "brand",
                    "value": "777"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "category_ids",
                    "value": [
                        "75",
                        "791",
                        "793",
                        "799"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "color",
                    "value": "5447"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "size",
                    "value": "5432"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "search_criteria": {
        "filter_groups": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "field": "category_id",
                        "value": "75",
                        "condition_type": "eq"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "sort_orders": [
            {
                "field": "position",
                "direction": "DESC"
            }
        ],
        "page_size": 3,
        "current_page": 1
    },
    "total_count": 3
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter nested array in object array by array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650390/filter-nested-array-in-object-array-by-array-of-values)

Comment: your question doesn't match with the data you supplied. Please review and correct as needed

Comment: @norbitrial thansk for your reference but it doesn't exactly worked for me

Comment: @DCR I hope I missed some thing. I have edited so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u try this filter.

```
function filter(brand,no){
        return el.items.filter(x=>x.custom_attributes.find(y=>y.attribute_code==brand && (y.value==no  || y.value.includes(no)) ))
}
```

and call it

```
filter("brand",777)
```

Comment: can u share an expected output please ?

Comment: I have updated my question. There are three products first but after filter I will get one product matching with the attribute_code brand and it's value of 777

Comment: u can share here or in question. but if u can do it in question . every answerers also will see it