# Nested array filtering

Tags: javascript, arrays

categories.location array is filtered like this:

```
  const displayedCategories = categories.filter(
    (category) => category.location.indexOf(selectedLocation) >= 0
  );
```

Now its structure is changed like below, there's additional nested values. How can I filter value/label now? `category.location.value.indexOf` doesn't work. Thanks.

```
"location" : [ 
    {
        "value" : "London",
        "label" : "London"
    }
             ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter nested array in object array by array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650390/filter-nested-array-in-object-array-by-array-of-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
const displayedCategories = categories.filter(
    (category) => category.location.some(loc=>loc.value==selectedLocation)
  );
```

Comment: It's better to do `category.location.some(loc => loc.value === selectedLocation)` so you finish after the first match is found rather than looping through everything and building an array just so you can inspect the length.

Comment: @Jacob, good catch!