# filter array of objects by value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to filter the object based on the array values given below. I know how to filter object through the key but in this scenario I need to filter it by values.

This is my code:

```
let _ = [{
        "form_id": "659d796d-aa78-4e74-af68-5ef037bb215b",
        "form_name": "Investigation Forms",
        "form_type": null,
        "created_at": "",
        "updated_at": ""
    },
    {
        "form_id": "9991f556-fc7f-4400-a491-062b12a0bb03",
        "form_name": "Other Investigation Forms",
        "form_type": {
            "form_type_name": "Assessment",
            "form_type_id": "5f4419c1-9351-4338-b894-84a000328cc4"
        },
        "created_at": "",
        "updated_at": ""
    },
    {
        "form_id": "9991f556-fc7f-4400-a491-062b12a0bb03",
        "form_name": "Other/General Investigation Forms",
        "form_type": {
            "form_type_name": "Report",
            "form_type_id": "594ba131-b110-4ec5-855a-9de8440fbc7b"
        },
        "created_at": "",
        "updated_at": ""
    }
]

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const values = [0, "5f4419c1-9351-4338-b894-84a000328cc4", "594ba131-b110-4ec5-855a-9de8440fbc7b"]

plz ignore my below code it is work attempt . 

const output = _.map(item =>
    values.reduce((val, key) => ({
        ...val,
        [key]: item[key]
    }), {})
);
console.log(output);
```

```
my expected output :
const values = ["5f4419c1-9351-4338-b894-84a000328cc4"]

output = [{
 "form_id": "9991f556-fc7f-4400-a491-062b12a0bb03",
        "form_name": "Other Investigation Forms",
        "form_type": {
            "form_type_name": "Assessment",
            "form_type_id": "5f4419c1-9351-4338-b894-84a000328cc4"
        },
        "created_at": "",
        "updated_at": ""
}]
```

The form_type has form_type_id, this is the value I need to be filter by.

Comment: You want to filter based on the value of `form_type. form_type_id` ?

Comment: @code yes brother i need like that

Comment: @code yes i need like thatt

Comment: What do you want to use as the logic for filtering? If the `form_type_id` exists, or if it has a specific value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter nested array in object array by array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650390/filter-nested-array-in-object-array-by-array-of-values)

Comment: can you post your desired output.

Comment: @ObedMarquezParlapiano specific value

Comment: i didnt get any answer till now plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then you need

```js
_.filter((item) => values.includes(item.form_type?.form_type_id));
```

or if optional chaining is not available (as correctly pointed out by Obed Marquez Parlapiano)

```js
_.filter((item) => values.includes(item.form_type && item.form_type.form_type_id));
```

See test at https://jsfiddle.net/snLqx4g9/

Comment: Note that you may not have access to optional chaining `?.`. In that case just use `item.form_type && item.form_type.form_type_id`

Comment: Array.contains are actually deprecated you might not be available in your browser. I have updated the answer and included Obed's comment as well

Comment: Added a jsfiddle link where you can play with this. If workink please accept answer.