# Filter an array of objects with null date values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, filter

I have an array of objects that contains events looking like this for example:

```
[
{
  "id": "abc123",
  "name": 
    {
      "fi": "The name of the event in finnish",
      "en": "The name of the event in english",
      "sv": "samma på svenska",
      "zh": "标题"
    },
      "description": {
        "intro": "",
        "body": ""
    },
      "event_dates": {
        "starting_day": "2025-10-24T16:00:00.000Z",
        "ending_day": "2025-10-24T17:00:00.000Z"
    }
  }
},
{
  "id": "123efg",
  "name": 
    {
      "fi": "The name of the event in finnish",
      "en": "The name of the event in english",
      "sv": "samma på svenska",
      "zh": "标题"
    },
      "description": {
        "intro": "",
        "body": ""
    },
      "event_dates": {
        "starting_day": null,
        "ending_day": null
    }
  }
]
```

However, some of the starting_day and ending_day values in the array are null. I need to write a function that would filter all the events where the date values are null and print out the array that only contains the events where the dates are not null. What could be the cleanest way to accomplish that?

Comment: Just use the `array.filter()` method, with a filtering function that checks that the starting and ending days are not null. Please show what you tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [filter array of objects by value in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66105916/filter-array-of-objects-by-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` method, and on each item in the array, check if `every` `value` in `event_dates` object are with `null` and then filter this item.

```js
const arr = [
{
  "id": "abc123",
  "name": 
    {
      "fi": "The name of the event in finnish",
      "en": "The name of the event in english",
      "sv": "samma på svenska",
      "zh": "标题"
    },
      "description": {
        "intro": "",
        "body": ""
    },
      "event_dates": {
        "starting_day": "2025-10-24T16:00:00.000Z",
        "ending_day": "2025-10-24T17:00:00.000Z"
    }
},
{
  "id": "123efg",
  "name": 
    {
      "fi": "The name of the event in finnish",
      "en": "The name of the event in english",
      "sv": "samma på svenska",
      "zh": "标题"
    },
      "description": {
        "intro": "",
        "body": ""
    },
      "event_dates": {
        "starting_day": null,
        "ending_day": null
    }
  }
]

const result = arr.filter(item => Object.values(item.event_dates).every(item => item === null))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, this one solved it. The every() method was the one I needed

Answer (score 0):

As long as all the objects are structured the same way you could simply do

```
const filteredArray = inputArray.filter(object => {
  object.event_dates.starting_day !== "null"
}
```

I will point out that the first object has an extra closing curly bracket

```
{1
  "id": "abc123",
  "name": 
    {2
      "fi": "The name of the event in finnish",
      "en": "The name of the event in english",
      "sv": "samma på svenska",
      "zh": "标题"
    1},
      "description": {3
        "intro": "",
        "body": ""
    2},
      "event_dates": {4
        "starting_day": "2025-10-24T16:00:00.000Z",
        "ending_day": "2025-10-24T17:00:00.000Z"
    3}
  4} 
5},
```

I would remove the 4th closing curly.